# UIImagePickerController back button/cancel button is not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

I show the phone's gallery with an UIImagePickerController, but there is no back/cancel button on it. How can I add one?

What I have (inside a UIViewController):

```swift
func openGallery() {
  let picker = UIImagePickerController()
  picker.allowsEditing = false
  picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
  picker.mediaTypes =
    UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
  present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When I run this, I get the gallery, however there is no cancel button at top where it usually is.

Comment: Did you implement the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` method? Did you set the `delegate` property of the image picker?

Comment: hi did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Implement `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate` and create a variable to assign UIImagePickerController `var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()`
and set `imagePicker.delegate = self`.

```
func openGallary()
{
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: There's nothing to import beyond UIKit. And there is no need to create the `imagePicker` property. The local variable in the OP's code is fine.